# Items Excluded from SQL Results Despite COALESCE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to pull all Item IDs bought by a customer since @StartDate. Some of the Item IDs have been changed since the part was sold so I added COALESCE to the SELECT statement hoping that it would return the new Item ID of a part, but the only parts that are being returned are those that have an Alternate Code. Item IDs that have never changed, and have no alternate code, are not in the results...and I'm not sure why.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p21_view_invoice_line.supplier_id 
                AS 
                [Supp ID], 
                address_1.NAME 
                AS Supplier, 
                address.NAME 
                AS Customer, 
                COALESCE(p21_view_alternate_code.item_id, 
                p21_view_invoice_line.item_id) AS 
                [Item ID], 
                p21_view_alternate_code.item_desc 
                AS [Item Desc], 
                p21_view_invoice_line.customer_part_number 
                AS CPN, 
                p21_view_invoice_line.unit_of_measure 
                AS UOM, 
                p21_view_invoice_hdr.order_no 
                AS [Order No], 
                p21_view_invoice_hdr.invoice_date 
                AS [Invoice Date], 
                p21_view_invoice_line.qty_shipped 
                AS [Qty Shipped], 
                p21_view_invoice_line.unit_price 
                AS [Last Invoiced Sales Price], 
                p21_view_invoice_line.commission_cost 
                AS [Last Invoice Comm Cost], 
                inv_loc.standard_cost 
                AS [Current Standard Cost] 
FROM   p21_view_invoice_hdr 
       INNER JOIN p21_view_invoice_line 
               ON p21_view_invoice_hdr.invoice_no = 
                  p21_view_invoice_line.invoice_no 
       INNER JOIN inv_loc 
               ON p21_view_invoice_line.company_id = inv_loc.company_id 
       INNER JOIN address AS address_1 
               ON p21_view_invoice_line.supplier_id = address_1.id 
       INNER JOIN address 
               ON p21_view_invoice_hdr.customer_id = address.id 
       INNER JOIN p21_view_alternate_code 
               ON inv_loc.inv_mast_uid = p21_view_alternate_code.inv_mast_uid 
                  AND p21_view_invoice_line.inv_mast_uid = 
                      p21_view_alternate_code.inv_mast_uid 
WHERE  ( p21_view_invoice_hdr.customer_id = @Customer_ID ) 
       AND ( p21_view_invoice_hdr.invoice_date >= @StartDate ) 
ORDER  BY [supp id], 
          [item id], 
          [invoice date] DESC, 
          [current standard cost] DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the code and included a FULL OUTER JOIN for the two Item ID identifiers columns, inv_mas_uid, and this solved the problem. A query takes about 2-3 seconds.

Here is the new query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
p21_view_invoice_line.supplier_id AS [Supp ID]
, address_1.name AS Supplier
, p21_view_invoice_hdr.customer_id AS [Customer ID]
, address.name AS Customer
, COALESCE (p21_view_alternate_code.item_id, p21_view_invoice_line.item_id) AS [Item ID]
, COALESCE (p21_view_alternate_code.item_desc, p21_view_invoice_line.item_desc) AS [Item Desc]
--, p21_view_invoice_line.inv_mast_uid
, p21_view_invoice_line.customer_part_number AS CPN
, p21_view_invoice_hdr.order_no AS [Order No]
, p21_view_invoice_hdr.invoice_date AS [Invoice Date]
, p21_view_invoice_line.qty_shipped AS [Qty Shipped]
, p21_view_invoice_line.unit_of_measure AS UOM
, p21_view_invoice_line.commission_cost AS [Comm Cost]
, p21_view_invoice_line.unit_price AS [Unit Price]
, inv_loc.standard_cost AS [Current Std Cost]

FROM            
address 
INNER JOIN p21_view_alternate_code 
FULL OUTER JOIN p21_view_invoice_line ON p21_view_alternate_code.inv_mast_uid = p21_view_invoice_line.inv_mast_uid 
INNER JOIN p21_view_invoice_hdr ON p21_view_invoice_line.invoice_no = p21_view_invoice_hdr.invoice_no 
INNER JOIN inv_loc ON p21_view_invoice_line.inv_mast_uid = inv_loc.inv_mast_uid 
INNER JOIN address AS address_1 ON p21_view_invoice_line.supplier_id = address_1.id ON address.id = p21_view_invoice_hdr.customer_id

WHERE     
(p21_view_invoice_hdr.customer_id = @Customer_ID)    
AND (p21_view_invoice_hdr.invoice_date >= @Begin_Date) 
--AND (p21_view_invoice_line.supplier_id = 9219) 
AND (p21_view_invoice_line.supplier_id IS NOT NULL)

ORDER BY 
[Supplier]
, [Invoice Date] DESC
, [Item ID]
```

Answer (score 1):

Strong hunch:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN p21_view_alternate_code
    ON  inv_loc.inv_mast_uid = p21_view_alternate_code.inv_mast_uid 
        AND p21_view_invoice_line.inv_mast_uid = p21_view_alternate_code.inv_mast_uid
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is right.  An inner join will exclude all rows that don't have an alternate ID.  A left join will keep all rows.

Comment: It seemed like a reasonable suggestion, but the query ran for ten minutes without results before I ended it.

Comment: With so little insight into the volume of data involved and the timing on your bad query it's a little hard to offer much. That last join is referencing three different tables so who know how long it should take.